# $f'$ decreasing everywhere but not defined in one point. Is $f$ concave?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Small issue: Suppose that $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, differentiable except on a finite set of points, let say in one point $y$.

For $x<y$ and $x>y$ we have $f''<0$. Moreover, $f'$ is larger on $[0,y[$ than on $]y,1]$. Overall: $f'$ is decreasing everywhere but not defined on $y$.

Can I say that $f$ is concave? Why?

Thank you

Comment: Seems that it should be concave, because $f'$ is decreasing and on $[a,y)$ is greater than on $(y,b]$

Comment: You can try to show that $-f$ has a nonempty subdifferential at $y$. At all other points, it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: visual idea for a proof:
[image]